# Trying to make a spinning cube but only shows a small white dot spinning?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame to make a 3D cube and make it spin but for some reason the output is just a small white dot. I think the cube is so small it looks like a dot.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from math import sin, cos

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Define cube vertices
vertices = [(x, y, z) for x in (-1, 1) for y in (-1, 1) for z in (-1, 1)]
edges = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 0), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]

# Define rotation function
def rotate(x, y, angle):
    return x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle), x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)

# Set initial rotation angles
angle_x, angle_y, angle_z = 0, 0, 0

# Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    # Clear screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Apply rotation to vertices
    rotated = []
    for x, y, z in vertices:
        # Rotate around x-axis
        y, z = rotate(y, z, angle_x)
        # Rotate around y-axis
        x, z = rotate(x, z, angle_y)
        # Rotate around z-axis
        x, y = rotate(x, y, angle_z)
        # Perspective projection
        f = 200
        scale = f / (f - z)
        x, y = x*scale, y*scale
        # Translate to screen coordinates
        x, y = int(x + screen.get_width() / 2), int(y + screen.get_height() / 2)
        rotated.append((x, y))

    # Draw edges
    for i, j in edges:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), rotated[i], rotated[j], 2)

    # Update rotation angles
    angle_x += 0.01
    angle_y += 0.02
    angle_z += 0.03

    # Update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: This is the output from the code.]

So I thought the windows was small so I made it bigger but it seems the cube isn't getting bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cube is too small. You have to scale the vertices:

```py
s = 20
for x, y, z in vertices:
    x, y, z = x*s, y*s, z*s

    # [...]
```

Alternatively can change the 2D coordinates when the geometry is projected on the display:

```py
for x, y, z in vertices:
    # [...]

    x, y = int(x * 20 + screen.get_width() / 2), int(y * 20 + screen.get_height() / 2)
    rotated.append((x, y))
```

[image]

Comment: I see. Thank you my code works now!